# Mysql select multiple tables but inner join on one table

Tags: mysql, inner-join, multiple-tables

Is it possible to select multiple tables and make inner join on one of those tables? e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2, table3 AS t3
INNER JOIN table4 AS t4 ON t1.row3 = t4.row3
INNER JOIN table5 AS t5 ON t1.row4 = t5.row4
WHERE ...
```

This paricular case is causing me a problem. it gives me an error - Unknown column "t1.row3" in 'on clause'. I don't know if it's possible to select multiple tables but make inner join on one of those tables.

Comment: Are these your actual table and column names?

Comment: no, these are not my actual tables and column names but it's similar. I need to select 3 tables, on one table i need to do inner join, and on other two tables just simple select.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `JOIN` operand has higher precedence than comma `,` operand, so the join is effectively treated as

```
t1, t2, (t3, t4, t5 ON ... )
```

Put parentheses around t1, t2, t3.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  ( table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2, table3 AS t3 )
INNER JOIN table4 AS t4 ON t1.row3 = t4.row3
INNER JOIN table5 AS t5 ON t1.row4 = t5.row4
WHERE ...
```

You can also write your query as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
INNER JOIN table3 AS t3
INNER JOIN table4 AS t4 ON t1.row3 = t4.row3
INNER JOIN table5 AS t5 ON t1.row4 = t5.row4
WHERE ...
```

because comma is equivalent to INNER JOIN without a join condition.

Comment: actually what i didnt see that now as results i get same row multiple times... row1,row1,row1,row2,row2,row2....